# Choosing symbology classification scheme for Solar PV Electricity Generation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I am presenting some data relating to rooftops suitable for solar PV and their potential PV electricity generation.

I am mapping the above data for the study area.

What would be the best symbology classification given the data? (Equal interval, Natural Break, Quantiles etc)

[image: Sreenshot of ArcGIS and the data]

Answer (score 1):

According to [ESRI's help docs](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/data-classification-methods.htm) here are a few pointers highlighted to take into consideration when choosing a classification method:

When you classify your data, you can use one of several standard classification methods or you can manually define your own custom class ranges.

***Standard classification methods in ArcGIS***

**Manual interval**

If you want to define your own classes, you can manually add class breaks and set class ranges that are appropriate for your data. Alternatively, you can start with one of the standard classifications and make adjustments as needed.

**Defined interval**

Defined interval allows you to specify an interval size used to define a series of classes with the same value range.

**Equal interval**

Equal interval is best applied to familiar data ranges, such as percentages and temperature. This method emphasizes the amount of an attribute value relative to other values. For example, it will show that a store is part of the group of stores that make up the top one-third of all sales.

**Quantile**

A quantile classification is well suited to linearly distributed data. Quantile assigns the same number of data values to each class. There are no empty classes or classes with too few or too many values.

Because features are grouped in equal numbers in each class using quantile classification, the resulting map can often be misleading. Similar features can be placed in adjacent classes, or features with widely different values can be put in the same class. You can minimize this distortion by increasing the number of classes.

**Natural breaks (Jenks)**

Natural breaks classes are based on natural groupings inherent in the data. Class breaks are identified that best group similar values and that maximize the differences between classes.

Natural breaks are data-specific classifications and not useful for comparing multiple maps built from different underlying information.

I would recommend using the Natural Breaks (Jenks) considering your dataset and the distribution of your data values.